# Need assistance moving set-returning functions in a CASE into a LATERAL join

Tags: postgresql

I have an application query that needs to be rewritten so the DB can be upgraded.   I've tried several things listed in the forums here like moving the set-returning functions to a lateral join but cant seem to get it working.   any help would be appreciated.   Original query below.

```
   SELECT id, name, description, owner, is_private, read_scopes, edit_scopes,
          CASE 
            WHEN jsonb_typeof(json_element) = 'array' 
            THEN jsonb_array_elements(json_element)
            WHEN jsonb_exists(json_element, 'children')
            THEN jsonb_array_elements(json_element -> 'children')
            END AS json_element
        FROM children
        WHERE  jsonb_typeof(json_element) = 'array' OR jsonb_typeof(json_element) = 'object'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the decision which array to unnest into the parameter passed to jsonb_array_elements():

```
select id, name, j.*
from children c
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(case 
                                   when jsonb_typeof(c.json_element) = 'array' then json_element 
                                   when jsonb_typeof(c.json_element -> 'children') = 'array' then json_element -> 'children'
                                  end) as j(json_element)
where jsonb_typeof(c.json_element) = 'array'
   or jsonb_typeof(c.json_element -> 'children') = 'array'
```

Comment: That works.   Much easier than what I was trying.  Thank you so much!